# How to solve "Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)"?

Tags: bluetooth

I use Ubuntu 23.10 (upgraded a few days ago from 23.04) and I start it with all Bluetooth devices off.

```
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci1: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

I have issues with hci0 (Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560) but not with hci1 (ASUS USB-BT500); when I run `sudo rfkill unblock 0` I get the outcome as below. What's the issue cause and how should I fix it?

```
sudo inxi -bE
System:
  Host: adrhc.go.ro Kernel: 6.5.0-17-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Console: pty pts/8 Distro: Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX H370-I GAMING v: Rev X.0x
    serial: 181038382100448 UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2811 date: 05/27/2020
CPU:
  Info: quad core Intel Core i3-8300 [MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 800
    min/max: 800/3700
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP) driver: btusb
    type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
    address: 18:1D:EA:13:34:FD
  Device-2: ASUSTek ASUS USB-BT500 driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: ID: hci1 state: up address: 08:BF:B8:53:C5:5B bt-v: 5.1

sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[77827.341796] Bluetooth: hci0: Hardware error 0x0c
[77827.352823] Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)
[77828.779885] Bluetooth: hci0: Hardware error 0x0c
[77828.790915] Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)

sudo journalctl --no-hostname -o short-full -xfu Bluetooth
# nothing new

tail -f /var/log/syslog
rfkill: unblock set for id 0
systemd[1]: Starting systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
systemd[1]: Started systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519864.2488] manager: (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/625)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519864.2496] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519864.2508] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
dbus-daemon[1327]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' unit='blueman-mechanism.service' requested by ':1.216' (uid=1002 pid=3134 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet" label="unconfined")
systemd[1]: Starting blueman-mechanism.service - Bluetooth management mechanism...
dbus-daemon[1327]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
systemd[1]: Started blueman-mechanism.service - Bluetooth management mechanism.
kernel: [77881.417836] Bluetooth: hci0: Hardware error 0x0c
kernel: [77881.428838] Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519865.6169] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519865.6838] manager: (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/626)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519865.6840] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519865.6845] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
kernel: [77882.855896] Bluetooth: hci0: Hardware error 0x0c
kernel: [77882.866936] Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519867.0566] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519867.1243] manager: (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/627)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519867.1260] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519867.1275] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
kernel: [77884.293879] Bluetooth: hci0: Hardware error 0x0c
kernel: [77884.304885] Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519868.4931] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519868.5598] manager: (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/628)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519868.5599] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519868.5602] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
kernel: [77885.731848] Bluetooth: hci0: Hardware error 0x0c
kernel: [77885.742873] Bluetooth: hci0: Retrieving Intel exception info failed (-16)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519869.9307] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519869.9977] manager: (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/629)
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519869.9985] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
NetworkManager[1451]: <info>  [1708519870.0063] device (34:B1:EB:91:52:FF): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
rfkill: block set for id 0

sudo btmon
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.68
= Note: Linux version 6.5.0-17-generic (x86_64)                                                                                                     0.793468
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                                            0.793474
= New Index: 08:BF:B8:53:C5:5B (Primary,USB,hci1)                                                                                            [hci1] 0.793477
= New Index: 18:1D:EA:13:34:FD (Primary,USB,hci0)                                                                                            [hci0] 0.793478
@ RAW Open: hcidump (privileged) version 2.22                                                                                       {0x0002} [hci0] 0.793480
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.22                                                                                          {0x0001} 0.793482
@ MGMT Command: Set Powered (0x0005) plen 1                                                                                        {0x0001} [hci0] 64.984031
        Powered: Enabled (0x01)
= Open Index: 18:1D:EA:13:34:FD                                                                                                             [hci0] 65.102004
< HCI Command: Reset (0x03|0x0003) plen 0                                                                                                #1 [hci0] 65.102317
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                              #2 [hci0] 65.113253
      Reset (0x03|0x0003) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: Read Local Supported Features (0x04|0x0003) plen 0                                                                        #3 [hci0] 65.113476
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12                                                                                             #4 [hci0] 65.114246
      Read Local Supported Features (0x04|0x0003) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
          3 slot packets
          5 slot packets
          Encryption
          Slot offset
          Timing accuracy
          Role switch
          Sniff mode
          Power control requests
          Channel quality driven data rate (CQDDR)
          SCO link
          HV2 packets
          HV3 packets
          u-law log synchronous data
          A-law log synchronous data
          CVSD synchronous data
          Paging parameter negotiation
          Power control
          Transparent synchronous data
          Enhanced Data Rate ACL 2 Mbps mode
          Enhanced Data Rate ACL 3 Mbps mode
          Enhanced inquiry scan
          Interlaced inquiry scan
          Interlaced page scan
          RSSI with inquiry results
          Extended SCO link (EV3 packets)
          EV4 packets
          EV5 packets
          AFH capable peripheral
          AFH classification peripheral
          LE Supported (Controller)
          3-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
          5-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
          Sniff subrating
          Pause encryption
          AFH capable central
          AFH classification central
          Enhanced Data Rate eSCO 2 Mbps mode
          Enhanced Data Rate eSCO 3 Mbps mode
          3-slot Enhanced Data Rate eSCO packets
          Extended Inquiry Response
          Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR (Controller)
          Secure Simple Pairing
          Encapsulated PDU
          Erroneous Data Reporting
          Non-flushable Packet Boundary Flag
          Link Supervision Timeout Changed Event
          Inquiry TX Power Level
          Enhanced Power Control
          Extended features
< HCI Command: Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) plen 0                                                                       #5 [hci0] 65.114380
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12                                                                                             #6 [hci0] 65.115215
      Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        HCI version: Bluetooth 5.1 (0x0a) - Revision 256 (0x0100)
        LMP version: Bluetooth 5.1 (0x0a) - Subversion 256 (0x0100)
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
< HCI Command: Read BD ADDR (0x04|0x0009) plen 0                                                                                         #7 [hci0] 65.115294
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10                                                                                             #8 [hci0] 65.116254
      Read BD ADDR (0x04|0x0009) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Address: 18:1D:EA:13:34:FD (Intel Corporate)
< HCI Command: Read Local Supported Commands (0x04|0x0002) plen 0                                                                        #9 [hci0] 65.116472
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 68                                                                                            #10 [hci0] 65.118221
      Read Local Supported Commands (0x04|0x0002) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Commands: 215 entries
          Inquiry (Octet 0 - Bit 0)
          Inquiry Cancel (Octet 0 - Bit 1)
          Periodic Inquiry Mode (Octet 0 - Bit 2)
          Exit Periodic Inquiry Mode (Octet 0 - Bit 3)
          Create Connection (Octet 0 - Bit 4)
          Disconnect (Octet 0 - Bit 5)
          Add SCO Connection (Octet 0 - Bit 6)
          Create Connection Cancel (Octet 0 - Bit 7)
          Accept Connection Request (Octet 1 - Bit 0)
          Reject Connection Request (Octet 1 - Bit 1)
          Link Key Request Reply (Octet 1 - Bit 2)
          Link Key Request Negative Reply (Octet 1 - Bit 3)
          PIN Code Request Reply (Octet 1 - Bit 4)
          PIN Code Request Negative Reply (Octet 1 - Bit 5)
          Change Connection Packet Type (Octet 1 - Bit 6)
          Authentication Requested (Octet 1 - Bit 7)
          Set Connection Encryption (Octet 2 - Bit 0)
          Change Connection Link Key (Octet 2 - Bit 1)
          Remote Name Request (Octet 2 - Bit 3)
          Remote Name Request Cancel (Octet 2 - Bit 4)
          Read Remote Supported Features (Octet 2 - Bit 5)
          Read Remote Extended Features (Octet 2 - Bit 6)
          Read Remote Version Information (Octet 2 - Bit 7)
          Read Clock Offset (Octet 3 - Bit 0)
          Read LMP Handle (Octet 3 - Bit 1)
          Sniff Mode (Octet 4 - Bit 2)
          Exit Sniff Mode (Octet 4 - Bit 3)
          QoS Setup (Octet 4 - Bit 6)
          Role Discovery (Octet 4 - Bit 7)
          Switch Role (Octet 5 - Bit 0)
          Read Link Policy Settings (Octet 5 - Bit 1)
          Write Link Policy Settings (Octet 5 - Bit 2)
          Read Default Link Policy Settings (Octet 5 - Bit 3)
          Write Default Link Policy Settings (Octet 5 - Bit 4)
          Flow Specification (Octet 5 - Bit 5)
          Set Event Mask (Octet 5 - Bit 6)
          Reset (Octet 5 - Bit 7)
          Set Event Filter (Octet 6 - Bit 0)
          Flush (Octet 6 - Bit 1)
          Read PIN Type (Octet 6 - Bit 2)
          Write PIN Type (Octet 6 - Bit 3)
          Read Stored Link Key (Octet 6 - Bit 5)
          Write Stored Link Key (Octet 6 - Bit 6)
          Delete Stored Link Key (Octet 6 - Bit 7)
          Write Local Name (Octet 7 - Bit 0)
          Read Local Name (Octet 7 - Bit 1)
          Read Connection Accept Timeout (Octet 7 - Bit 2)
          Write Connection Accept Timeout (Octet 7 - Bit 3)
          Read Page Timeout (Octet 7 - Bit 4)
          Write Page Timeout (Octet 7 - Bit 5)
          Read Scan Enable (Octet 7 - Bit 6)
          Write Scan Enable (Octet 7 - Bit 7)
          Read Page Scan Activity (Octet 8 - Bit 0)
          Write Page Scan Activity (Octet 8 - Bit 1)
          Read Inquiry Scan Activity (Octet 8 - Bit 2)
          Write Inquiry Scan Activity (Octet 8 - Bit 3)
          Read Authentication Enable (Octet 8 - Bit 4)
          Write Authentication Enable (Octet 8 - Bit 5)
          Read Encryption Mode (Octet 8 - Bit 6)
          Write Encryption Mode (Octet 8 - Bit 7)
          Read Class of Device (Octet 9 - Bit 0)
          Write Class of Device (Octet 9 - Bit 1)
          Read Voice Setting (Octet 9 - Bit 2)
          Write Voice Setting (Octet 9 - Bit 3)
          Read Automatic Flush Timeout (Octet 9 - Bit 4)
          Write Automatic Flush Timeout (Octet 9 - Bit 5)
          Read Transmit Power Level (Octet 10 - Bit 2)
          Read Sync Flow Control Enable (Octet 10 - Bit 3)
          Write Sync Flow Control Enable (Octet 10 - Bit 4)
          Set Controller To Host Flow Control (Octet 10 - Bit 5)
          Host Buffer Size (Octet 10 - Bit 6)
          Host Number of Completed Packets (Octet 10 - Bit 7)
          Read Link Supervision Timeout (Octet 11 - Bit 0)
          Write Link Supervision Timeout (Octet 11 - Bit 1)
          Read Number of Supported IAC (Octet 11 - Bit 2)
          Read Current IAC LAP (Octet 11 - Bit 3)
          Write Current IAC LAP (Octet 11 - Bit 4)
          Read Page Scan Mode (Octet 11 - Bit 7)
          Write Page Scan Mode (Octet 12 - Bit 0)
          Set AFH Host Channel Classification (Octet 12 - Bit 1)
          Read Inquiry Scan Type (Octet 12 - Bit 4)
          Write Inquiry Scan Type (Octet 12 - Bit 5)
          Read Inquiry Mode (Octet 12 - Bit 6)
          Write Inquiry Mode (Octet 12 - Bit 7)
          Read Page Scan Type (Octet 13 - Bit 0)
          Write Page Scan Type (Octet 13 - Bit 1)
          Read AFH Channel Assessment Mode (Octet 13 - Bit 2)
          Write AFH Channel Assessment Mode (Octet 13 - Bit 3)
          Read Local Version Information (Octet 14 - Bit 3)
          Read Local Supported Features (Octet 14 - Bit 5)
          Read Local Extended Features (Octet 14 - Bit 6)
          Read Buffer Size (Octet 14 - Bit 7)
          Read BD ADDR (Octet 15 - Bit 1)
          Read Failed Contact Counter (Octet 15 - Bit 2)
          Reset Failed Contact Counter (Octet 15 - Bit 3)
          Read Link Quality (Octet 15 - Bit 4)
          Read RSSI (Octet 15 - Bit 5)
          Read AFH Channel Map (Octet 15 - Bit 6)
          Read Clock (Octet 15 - Bit 7)
          Read Loopback Mode (Octet 16 - Bit 0)
          Write Loopback Mode (Octet 16 - Bit 1)
          Enable Device Under Test Mode (Octet 16 - Bit 2)
          Setup Synchronous Connection (Octet 16 - Bit 3)
          Accept Synchronous Connection Request (Octet 16 - Bit 4)
          Reject Synchronous Connection Request (Octet 16 - Bit 5)
          Read Extended Inquiry Response (Octet 17 - Bit 0)
          Write Extended Inquiry Response (Octet 17 - Bit 1)
          Refresh Encryption Key (Octet 17 - Bit 2)
          Sniff Subrating (Octet 17 - Bit 4)
          Read Simple Pairing Mode (Octet 17 - Bit 5)
          Write Simple Pairing Mode (Octet 17 - Bit 6)
          Read Local OOB Data (Octet 17 - Bit 7)
          Read Inquiry Response TX Power Level (Octet 18 - Bit 0)
          Write Inquiry Transmit Power Level (Octet 18 - Bit 1)
          Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting (Octet 18 - Bit 2)
          Write Default Erroneous Data Reporting (Octet 18 - Bit 3)
          IO Capability Request Reply (Octet 18 - Bit 7)
          User Confirmation Request Reply (Octet 19 - Bit 0)
          User Confirmation Request Neg Reply (Octet 19 - Bit 1)
          User Passkey Request Reply (Octet 19 - Bit 2)
          User Passkey Request Negative Reply (Octet 19 - Bit 3)
          Remote OOB Data Request Reply (Octet 19 - Bit 4)
          Write Simple Pairing Debug Mode (Octet 19 - Bit 5)
          Enhanced Flush (Octet 19 - Bit 6)
          Remote OOB Data Request Neg Reply (Octet 19 - Bit 7)
          Send Keypress Notification (Octet 20 - Bit 2)
          IO Capability Request Negative Reply (Octet 20 - Bit 3)
          Read Encryption Key Size (Octet 20 - Bit 4)
          Set Event Mask Page 2 (Octet 22 - Bit 2)
          Read Enhanced Transmit Power Level (Octet 24 - Bit 0)
          Read LE Host Supported (Octet 24 - Bit 5)
          Write LE Host Supported (Octet 24 - Bit 6)
          LE Set Event Mask (Octet 25 - Bit 0)
          LE Read Buffer Size (Octet 25 - Bit 1)
          LE Read Local Supported Features (Octet 25 - Bit 2)
          LE Set Random Address (Octet 25 - Bit 4)
          LE Set Advertising Parameters (Octet 25 - Bit 5)
          LE Read Advertising Channel TX Power (Octet 25 - Bit 6)
          LE Set Advertising Data (Octet 25 - Bit 7)
          LE Set Scan Response Data (Octet 26 - Bit 0)
          LE Set Advertise Enable (Octet 26 - Bit 1)
          LE Set Scan Parameters (Octet 26 - Bit 2)
          LE Set Scan Enable (Octet 26 - Bit 3)
          LE Create Connection (Octet 26 - Bit 4)
          LE Create Connection Cancel (Octet 26 - Bit 5)
          LE Read Accept List Size (Octet 26 - Bit 6)
          LE Clear Accept List (Octet 26 - Bit 7)
          LE Add Device To Accept List (Octet 27 - Bit 0)
          LE Remove Device From Accept List (Octet 27 - Bit 1)
          LE Connection Update (Octet 27 - Bit 2)
          LE Set Host Channel Classification (Octet 27 - Bit 3)
          LE Read Channel Map (Octet 27 - Bit 4)
          LE Read Remote Used Features (Octet 27 - Bit 5)
          LE Encrypt (Octet 27 - Bit 6)
          LE Rand (Octet 27 - Bit 7)
          LE Start Encryption (Octet 28 - Bit 0)
          LE Long Term Key Request Reply (Octet 28 - Bit 1)
          LE Long Term Key Request Neg Reply (Octet 28 - Bit 2)
          LE Read Supported States (Octet 28 - Bit 3)
          LE Receiver Test (Octet 28 - Bit 4)
          LE Transmitter Test (Octet 28 - Bit 5)
          LE Test End (Octet 28 - Bit 6)
          Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection (Octet 29 - Bit 3)
          Enhanced Accept Synchronous Connection Request (Octet 29 - Bit 4)
          Read Local Supported Codecs (Octet 29 - Bit 5)
          Set External Frame Configuration (Octet 29 - Bit 7)
          Remote OOB Extended Data Request Reply (Octet 32 - Bit 1)
          Read Secure Connections Host Support (Octet 32 - Bit 2)
          Write Secure Connections Host Support (Octet 32 - Bit 3)
          Read Authenticated Payload Timeout (Octet 32 - Bit 4)
          Write Authenticated Payload Timeout (Octet 32 - Bit 5)
          Read Local OOB Extended Data (Octet 32 - Bit 6)
          Write Secure Connections Test Mode (Octet 32 - Bit 7)
          Read Extended Page Timeout (Octet 33 - Bit 0)
          Write Extended Page Timeout (Octet 33 - Bit 1)
          Read Extended Inquiry Length (Octet 33 - Bit 2)
          Write Extended Inquiry Length (Octet 33 - Bit 3)
          LE Remote Connection Parameter Request Reply (Octet 33 - Bit 4)
          LE Remote Connection Parameter Request Negative Reply (Octet 33 - Bit 5)
          LE Set Data Length (Octet 33 - Bit 6)
          LE Read Suggested Default Data Length (Octet 33 - Bit 7)
          LE Write Suggested Default Data Length (Octet 34 - Bit 0)
          LE Read Local P-256 Public Key (Octet 34 - Bit 1)
          LE Generate DHKey (Octet 34 - Bit 2)
          LE Add Device To Resolving List (Octet 34 - Bit 3)
          LE Remove Device From Resolving List (Octet 34 - Bit 4)
          LE Clear Resolving List (Octet 34 - Bit 5)
          LE Read Resolving List Size (Octet 34 - Bit 6)
          LE Read Peer Resolvable Address (Octet 34 - Bit 7)
          LE Read Local Resolvable Address (Octet 35 - Bit 0)
          LE Set Address Resolution Enable (Octet 35 - Bit 1)
          LE Set Resolvable Private Address Timeout (Octet 35 - Bit 2)
          LE Read Maximum Data Length (Octet 35 - Bit 3)
          LE Read PHY (Octet 35 - Bit 4)
          LE Set Default PHY (Octet 35 - Bit 5)
          LE Set PHY (Octet 35 - Bit 6)
          LE Enhanced Receiver Test (Octet 35 - Bit 7)
          LE Enhanced Transmitter Test (Octet 36 - Bit 0)
          LE Set Advertising Set Random Address (Octet 36 - Bit 1)
          LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters (Octet 36 - Bit 2)
          LE Set Extended Advertising Data (Octet 36 - Bit 3)
          LE Set Extended Scan Response Data (Octet 36 - Bit 4)
          LE Set Extended Advertising Enable (Octet 36 - Bit 5)
          LE Read Maximum Advertising Data Length (Octet 36 - Bit 6)
          LE Read Number of Supported Advertising Sets (Octet 36 - Bit 7)
          LE Remove Advertising Set (Octet 37 - Bit 0)
          LE Clear Advertising Sets (Octet 37 - Bit 1)
          LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (Octet 37 - Bit 5)
          LE Set Extended Scan Enable (Octet 37 - Bit 6)
          LE Extended Create Connection (Octet 37 - Bit 7)
          LE Read Transmit Power (Octet 38 - Bit 7)
          LE Read RF Path Compensation (Octet 39 - Bit 0)
          LE Write RF Path Compensation (Octet 39 - Bit 1)
          LE Set Privacy Mode (Octet 39 - Bit 2)
          Read Local Simple Pairing Options (Octet 41 - Bit 3)
< HCI Command: Write Simple Pairing Mode (0x03|0x0056) plen 1                                                                           #11 [hci0] 65.118341
        Mode: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                             #12 [hci0] 65.119214
      Write Simple Pairing Mode (0x03|0x0056) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: Write Inquiry Mode (0x03|0x0045) plen 1                                                                                  #13 [hci0] 65.119279
        Mode: Inquiry Result with RSSI or Extended Inquiry Result (0x02)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                             #14 [hci0] 65.120214
      Write Inquiry Mode (0x03|0x0045) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: Read Inquiry Response TX Power Level (0x03|0x0058) plen 0                                                                #15 [hci0] 65.120281
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 5                                                                                             #16 [hci0] 65.121211
      Read Inquiry Response TX Power Level (0x03|0x0058) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        TX power: 12 dbm (0x0c)
< HCI Command: Read Local Extended Features (0x04|0x0004) plen 1                                                                        #17 [hci0] 65.121268
        Page: 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14                                                                                            #18 [hci0] 65.122216
      Read Local Extended Features (0x04|0x0004) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Page: 1/2
        Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          Secure Simple Pairing (Host Support)
< HCI Command: Read Buffer Size (0x04|0x0005) plen 0                                                                                    #19 [hci0] 65.122274
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 11                                                                                            #20 [hci0] 65.123275
      Read Buffer Size (0x04|0x0005) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        ACL MTU: 1021 ACL max packet: 4
        SCO MTU: 96   SCO max packet: 6
< HCI Command: Read Class of Device (0x03|0x0023) plen 0                                                                                #21 [hci0] 65.123329
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7                                                                                             #22 [hci0] 65.124251
      Read Class of Device (0x03|0x0023) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Class: 0x000000
          Major class: Miscellaneous
          Minor class: 0x00
< HCI Command: Read Local Name (0x03|0x0014) plen 0                                                                                     #23 [hci0] 65.124367
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 252                                                                                           #24 [hci0] 65.128287
      Read Local Name (0x03|0x0014) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Name:
< HCI Command: Read Voice Setting (0x03|0x0025) plen 0                                                                                  #25 [hci0] 65.128490
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 6                                                                                             #26 [hci0] 65.129224
      Read Voice Setting (0x03|0x0025) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Setting: 0x0060
          Input Coding: Linear
          Input Data Format: 2's complement
          Input Sample Size: 16-bit
          # of bits padding at MSB: 0
          Air Coding Format: CVSD
< HCI Command: Read Number of Supported IAC (0x03|0x0038) plen 0                                                                        #27 [hci0] 65.129345
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 5                                                                                             #28 [hci0] 65.130265
      Read Number of Supported IAC (0x03|0x0038) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Number of IAC: 2
< HCI Command: Read Current IAC LAP (0x03|0x0039) plen 0                                                                                #29 [hci0] 65.130459
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 8
```

Comment: This might be caused by booting with it blocked

Comment: I said: "when I run sudo rfkill unblock 0 I get the outcome as below", only then the error occurs. It also occurs if I boot with that Bluetooth device unblocked.

Comment: You could try `sudo modprobe- r btusb && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe btusb` after unblocking and see if it works

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I wonder if the wifi card needs to be removed from the motherboard and then put back in, might just be a connection issue causing this

Comment: My motherboard is Asus Rog Strix H370-I Gaming having embedded Bluetooth.